# Is there a way to enable gravity physics after keyframing an object?

Tags: animation, physics, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

I am working on a project in blender to get a set of objects first moving straight and then off a cliff. I first used keyframes to get my object going to where I want it to go,(edge of cliff) however after the last keyframe it just stays in that position(positioned off of cliff). I tried putting on rigid bodies, also enabling animated, but the object just stays in place(It does not animate gravity physics after the last keyframe).

It looks like you can either use physics or keyframes but not both, unless there is a method to get around this that I am not aware of. If there is a way to enable gravity physics after keyframing can you describe the process? Pictures or videos would help a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have an object animated in between 1 and 50 frames, and then, on 51 you want to drop it.
In this case, you should animate "Animated" property in Rigid body.
Go to on 50 frame (or any frame before 51st) and press dot icon near "Animated" property. This will create a keyframe, and you will see a checkbox will becomes yellow:

[image: frame 50]

When go to 51st frame and uncheck, if you see that checkbox is green, press again on diamond icon, to create second keyframe.

[image: frame 51]

You should end with this animation:

[image]

After doing this, the object will be animated until the 51st frame, where physics will be activated and the object will drop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I still could get physics working. When I keyframe the rigid body it does not work. Is there a video I can watch that explains this?

Comment: Make sure that "Animated" property is unchecked during animation.

Comment: I tried replicating this on a simpler object (default cube), and got the same animation keyframe set as you shown, however it just resets to the beginning and does not enable physics. I have no idea if I am missing something or if there is something wrong with my Blender.